# Why is the windows-curses module not working in the VSCode terminal or the Windows Terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

First time using Python in VSCode and I'm having trouble running a simple snake game in the terminal. When I execute the code, there's no response—no errors, messages, or execution. Any insights on why it might not be working? Could it be related to IDE settings, permissions, or my Python version? I'm using Python 3.12.0

Here's the code:

```
# Importing necessary libraries
import curses
import time
import random

# Screen configuration
screen = curses.initscr()
curses.curs_set(0)
screen_height, screen_width = screen.getmaxyx()
window = curses.newwin(screen_height, screen_width, 0, 0)
    

# Snake configuration
snake_x = screen_width // 4
snake_y = screen_height // 2
snake = [
    [snake_y, snake_x],
    [snake_y, snake_x - 1],
    [snake_y, snake_x - 2]
]

# Food configuration
food = [screen_height // 2, screen_width // 2]
window.addch(int(food[0]), int(food[1]), curses.ACS_PI)

# Snake movement
key = curses.KEY_RIGHT
while True:
    next_key = window.getch()
    key = key if next_key == -1 else next_key

    # Check if the snake has lost
    if (
        snake[0][0] in [0, screen_height] or
        snake[0][1] in [0, screen_width] or
        snake[0] in snake[1:]
    ):
        curses.endwin()
        quit()

    # New snake head point
    new_head = [snake[0][0], snake[0][1]]
    if key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
        new_head[0] += 1
    if key == curses.KEY_UP:
        new_head[0] -= 1
    if key == curses.KEY_LEFT:
        new_head[1] -= 1
    if key == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
        new_head[1] += 1
    snake.insert(0, new_head)

    # Check if the snake has eaten the food
    if snake[0] == food:
        food = None
        while food is None:
            new_food = [
                random.randint(1, screen_height - 1),
                random.randint(1, screen_width - 1)
            ]
            food = new_food if new_food not in snake else None
        window.addch(int(food[0]), int(food[1]), curses.ACS_PI)
    else:
        tail = snake.pop()
        window.addch(int(tail[0]), int(tail[1]), ' ')

    # Draw the snake
    window.addch(int(snake[0][0]), int(snake[0][1]), curses.ACS_CKBOARD)
```

[image: Output]

I tested it on other IDES and it works. I don't know why it doesn'y in Windows VSCode

Comment: have you tried any other VS Code terminal profiles other than the builtin PowerShell one?

Comment: @starball I also used CMD and still the same result

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Atm, I can get it to work using GitHub code spaces, i.e., VsCode online. I also got it to work on my normal terminal. It just doesn't work in the integrated terminal which sucks...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).